# expiry download links in c# and asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Temporary file download link with ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323949/temporary-file-download-link-with-asp-net)
>   [Create temporary link for download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703201/create-temporary-link-for-download)

I use ASP.NET
I need to give user temporary link for downloading file from server.
It should be a temporary link (page), which is available for a short time (12 hours for example). How can I generate this link (or temporary web page with link)?